# Find called javascript function in client side

Tags: javascript, function, firefox-addon, add-on

As a client I want to find out which one of javascript functions is called during exploring a web page.
is there an Add-ons or other tools to listen and return called function?(such as Live http header which listen all requests)
for example I want to find out which function is called when I click on an object in a web page.

Comment: You can use the debug tool that comes with the browser.

Comment: suggest me a good debug tool!

Comment: Chome and/or Firefox has it built in

Comment: Hit `F12` to get started.

Comment: between 100 function how to find out which one of them is called?!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox addons require special debugging. See the section here to set the appropriate preferences:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Development_preferences

After you do that, then open Browser Console with Ctrl (Apple key on Mac) + Shift + J and then you can see the error reports.

Before I learned of this, I struggled endlessly to debug my addons.

I updated the MDN extensions landing page as this should be made clear in step 0, i recall i couldn't even get started with addon dev for months because i couldnt find where i made the mistake and would continually re-read my sourcecode. Updated MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons